# Can't log in to spotify app

Tags: spotify

[image]

[image]

login screen doesn't appear.
I am using snap version of spotify,ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. But I solved it by installing chrome...
It seems like spotify-client expects chrome to be present to login in via the browser.

Hope it works for you.